# Redirect to specific page on all Errors(404, 405, etc)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have been thinking about it for quite some time but never actually got the time to do some research on it, but now this has returned to haunt me as a requirement,

I wanted to know; is there a way to redirect all errors to specific page in php, for example i know, that .htaccess file can be used for this purpose whenever there is a 404 error it is automatically redirected to some error page or funny 404 page,

i want to know if there is another way to redirect with all other errors like php script error and authenticity error etc..

Comment: Use a php file as an ErrorDocument: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/custom-error-pages/

Comment: Great answer, am testing it right now, could you also right this as an answer so i can mark it as correct answer once i have tested it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a php script as an Error document. Use this syntax in .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /your-file.php
```

Inside the php file you can use `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']`:

```
<?php

$status=$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'];
$codes=array(
      400 => array('400 Bad Request', 
                   'The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax.'),
      401 => array('401 Login Error', 
                   'It appears that the password and/or user-name you entered was incorrect.'),
      500 => array('500 Internal Server Error',
                   'The request was unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server.'),
      //all the other necessary codes
);

if(isset($codes[$status])){
    $errortitle=$codes[$status][0];
    $message=$codes[$status][1];
}
else{
    $errortitle="Unknown Error";
    $message="An unknown error has occurred. Code: $status.";
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo("$errortitle");?></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<?php
echo('<h1>'.$errortitle.'</h1>');
echo('<p>'.$message.'</p>');
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
header("405",true,405);
```

to redirect HTTP ERROR 405